# Tomcat started but localhost 8080 is not availble

Tags: java, tomcat

I have struggle on this for hours.

I have a java web project which runs well before(2 or 3 months before though), but today I found something wrong when I run the project in IDEA that  localhost:8080 is not working.

So I suspect if tomcat has problem. I stop my IDEA, restart my computer(personal) and start tomcat with /bin/startup.bat , tried to access the default tomcat index. But still not working.

I had tried to download a new tomcat(apache-tomcat-7.0.65) and did not do any modification. Then redo above(startup->try to access localhost:8080). Still not working.

At chorme, localhost:8080 gives me :"ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".

[image: tomcat started]
[image: 8080 is listening on]
[image: tomcat started and is listening on 8080]
[image]

Comment: you tried http://127.0.0.1:8080 as well I suspect? Maybe place simple jsp into webapps/ROOT/ just to recheck. Any antivirus or similar running at your local PC?

Comment: Check if tomcat is running on 8080 port using netstat -a | grep 8080

Comment: @Jan 1.had tried 127, the same. 3 I copy the default index.jsp to myjsp.jsp and tried http://localhost:8080/myjsp.jsp and http://localhost:8080/index.jsp, the same result. 3.Should not have, I shutdown all I know about proxy or antivirus software

Comment: @Naruto, had tried, check my screenshot

Comment: Have you tried telnet localhost 8080 and then a simple GET / HTTP/1.1  just to make sure it's  a tomcat problem and not a chrome one

Comment: You may copy pasted old server.xml in your tomcat installation. make sure connector port is 8080 in your server.xml

Comment: Did you figure it out yet? Have you checked local (Windows) firewall?

Answer (score 1):

You can run below commands. is this what you looking for?

```
 ./catalina.sh run
```

**Note**: Make sure the port 8080 is open. If not, kill the process that is using 8080 port using `sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)`